# LDAP connection to AD using OPENQUERY SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, sql-server-2008-r2, ldap

I have a query (below) that uses ldap connection to retrieve AD related info.  However, the issue is this query provide all of the employees.  I am only looking for current employees.  I was told to use following information to pull "Active only" employees:

> OU=CompanyName Users,DC=CompanyName,DC=local

I tried to modify below select statement to add OU related information, but query keeps failing.  Anyone know how to convert above string into a proper ldap location?

```
SELECT  
*
FROM OPENQUERY( ADLink, 
'
SELECT 
   employeeNumber,
   name
FROM ''LDAP://ldap.CompanyName.local/DC=CompanyName;DC=local''
WHERE objectClass = ''user'' 
  AND objectCategory = ''Person''   
ORDER BY title asc
') A
```

Comment: Try selecting only those objects which are enabled! It should help you achieve the desired result.

Comment: How do I know which ones are enabled?  Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Check this link -> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/44048e98-b191-4d18-9839-d79ffad86f76/ldap-query-for-all-active-users?forum=winserverDS

Answer (score 0):

There is an `accountExpires` attribute that you could probably filter on.

```
where accountExpires > 0
```

Just add `accountExpires` to your select list before you add it to the where clause to see the value returned. It should be the same format as your server.

Comment: May be we aren't using accountExpires attribute properly.  It is removing lots of active employees from the list when I filter by greater than 0.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well you may put an expiration date on the account that's in the future so i'd see what values are being returned and convert those to dates so you can tell. or just ask your ldap / security team.

Comment: In addition, how would I escape space in OU ("CompanyName Users") when writing ldap url:   LDAP://ldap.CompanyName.local/OU=CompanyName Users;DC=CompanyName;DC=local

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not correct
FROM ''LDAP://ldap.CompanyName.local/DC=CompanyName;DC=local''

Try:
FROM ''LDAP://OU="Organization Unit", DC="CompanyName",DC=com''